# Submitting AWS Datapipe job via java sdk to non-default queue failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I have configured my EMR cluster to have a 2nd hadoop queue.  The 'default' queue and one I've named 'gold'.
The queue is present and running when my EMR cluster starts up as I see it in the Hadoop web interface for Yarn.

My java code creates a pipeline job (HiveActivity in this case) and I add a list of Field objects to the Pipeline object. These Fields are the settings for the pipeline.

One such field (optional according to the docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-hiveactivity.html)  is the 'hadoopQueue'.  When I don't set this field is uses the 'default' queue by default. The job completes and all is well.

When I set the field with this code

```
//hadoopQueue
field = new Field();
field.setKey("hadoopQueue");
field.setStringValue("gold");
fields.add(field);
```

The job doesn't complete and I get the following error in my data pipeline logs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Local file does not exist.
at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.scriptrunner.ScriptRunner.fetchFile(ScriptRunner.java:30)
at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.scriptrunner.ScriptRunner.main(ScriptRunner.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

I also get this error if I explicitly set the queue to 'default' like

```
//hadoopQueue
  field = new Field();
  field.setKey("hadoopQueue");
  field.setStringValue("default");
  fields.add(field);
```

It only seems to work when I don't set this option but not using it means I can't specify another queue.

Has anyone been able to successful use the 'hadoopQueue' option in this manner?

```
public static String scheduleDataPipelineActivity(DataPipeline dpl, String pipelineId, String script, String stepName,
  Map<String,String> params) {

PutPipelineDefinitionRequest putDefReq = new PutPipelineDefinitionRequest();
putDefReq.setPipelineId(pipelineId);
List<PipelineObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();

List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();

Field field = new Field();
field.setKey("failureAndRerunMode");
field.setStringValue("CASCADE");
fields.add(field);

field = new Field();
field.setKey("resourceRole");
field.setStringValue("DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole");
fields.add(field);

field = new Field();
field.setKey("role");
field.setStringValue("DataPipelineDefaultRole");
fields.add(field);

field = new Field();
field.setKey("pipelineLogUri");
field.setStringValue("s3://" + getBucketName() + "/logs");
fields.add(field);

field = new Field();
field.setKey("scheduleType");
field.setStringValue("ONDEMAND");
fields.add(field);

if ((params != null) && (params.size() > 0)) {
  for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
    field = new Field();
    field.setKey("scriptVariable");
    field.setStringValue(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
    fields.add(field);
  }
}

PipelineObject po = new PipelineObject().withName("Default").withId("Default");
po.setFields(fields);
objects.add(po);

fields = new ArrayList<>();
field = new Field();
field.setKey("stage");
field.setStringValue("false");
fields.add(field);

field = new Field();
if (script.startsWith("s3://")) {
  field.setKey("scriptUri");
}
else if (script.length() > 2048) {

  field.setKey("scriptUri");
  Writer writer = null;
  try {
    String hiveQL = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".q";
    File localFile = new File(hiveQL);
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(localFile), "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(script);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    writer = null;

    String s3Key = "working/" + hiveQL;
    script = "s3://" + getBucketName() + "/" + s3Key;

    AmazonS3 s3 = getS3Client(null);
    s3.putObject(getBucketName(), s3Key, localFile);
    if (!localFile.delete()) {
      LOGGER.error("Unable to delete temporary file: " + hiveQL);
    }
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
  }
  finally {
    if (writer != null) {
      try {
        writer.close();
      }
      catch(IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
      }
    }
  }
}
else {
  field.setKey("hiveScript");
}
field.setStringValue(script);
fields.add(field);

field = new Field();
field.setKey("workerGroup");
field.setStringValue(EMR_INSTANCE);
fields.add(field);

hadoopQueue
field = new Field();
field.setKey("hadoopQueue");
field.setStringValue("gold");
fields.add(field);

field = new Field();
field.setKey("type");
field.setStringValue("HiveActivity");
fields.add(field);

String hiveId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
po = new PipelineObject().withName(stepName).withId(hiveId);
po.setFields(fields);
objects.add(po);

putDefReq.setPipelineObjects(objects);
PutPipelineDefinitionResult putPipelineResult = dpl.putPipelineDefinition(putDefReq);
List<ValidationError> errors = putPipelineResult.getValidationErrors();
int errorCount = 0;
if ((errors != null) && (errors.size() > 0)) {
  for (ValidationError error : errors) {
    List<String> errorStrs = error.getErrors();
    for (String errorStr : errorStrs) {
      LOGGER.error(errorStr);
      errorCount++;
    }
  }
}

List<ValidationWarning> warnings = putPipelineResult.getValidationWarnings();
if ((warnings != null) && (warnings.size() > 0)) {
  for (ValidationWarning warning : warnings) {
    List<String> warningStrs = warning.getWarnings();
    for (String warningStr : warningStrs) {
      LOGGER.warn(warningStr);
    }
  }
}

if (errorCount > 0) {
  LOGGER.fatal("BAD STUFF HAPPENED!!!!");
  throw new DataPipelineValidationException("Validation errors detected for hive activity (check log file for details): " +
      "step=" + stepName + "\terror count=" + Integer.toString(errorCount) + "\t" + pipelineId);
}

ActivatePipelineRequest activateReq = new ActivatePipelineRequest();
activateReq.setPipelineId(pipelineId);
dpl.activatePipeline(activateReq);

try {
  Thread.sleep(2500L);
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
  LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
}

return hiveId;
```

Comment: Have you tried creating the DP directly through the design UI and selecting your queue, and see if that works ?

Comment: Can you post more of the Java code that is configuring your PipelineObject?

Comment: I have added the method where we schedule the pipeline activity and set the fields.  The dataPipleline object is the AWS object returned by DataPipelineClientBuilder and pipelineId parameter is from getPipelineId on CreatePipelineResult object.